# mat-select value not saved on route change, Angular 8

Tags: angular

The value selected for the "Select Your Publication" dropdown is not saving in the dropdown when the user navigates away and then back on a button that uses routerState.snapshot (does collect the correct route).  The dropdown goes back to the placeholder ("All").
The dropdown "Select your model" works perfectly in saving the selection.  Since the publication dropdown awaits the model selection, maybe Angular is loading in the wrong order (?).  When I console log the this.selectedManual it always returns undefined.  Console log of this.selectedModel returns the correct value.

component.ts...

```
...

manuals: Toc[];
  models: string[];
  selectedModel: string;
  selectedManual: any;

  routerSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private productService: UserProductService,
    private tocService: TocService,
    private routeService: RouteService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public offlineService: OfflineService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getModels();
    this.trackRoute();

    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(
      (event: Event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.trackRoute();
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("model  " + this.selectedModel);
    console.log("manual  " + this.selectedManual);


  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.routerSubscription) {
      this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  async trackRoute(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.route.snapshot.children.length > 0) {
      const routeModelName = this.routeService.getParameter('model');
      const routeManualName = this.routeService.getParameter('manual');
      this.selectedModel = routeModelName;
      await this.loadManuals();
      this.selectedManual = this.getManualFromManualList(routeManualName);
    }
  }

  getModels() {
    this.productService.getUserModels()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.models = data;
    })
  }

  changeModel(event) {
    this.selectedModel = event.value;
    this.loadManuals();
    this.router.navigate(['toc', this.selectedModel]);
  }

  loadManuals() {
    this.manuals = undefined;
    this.selectedManual = undefined;
    if (this.selectedModel) {
      this.tocService.getModelToc(this.selectedModel)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.manuals = data.toc;
      });
    }
  }

  changeManual(event) {
    this.selectedManual = this.getManualFromManualList(event.value);
    if (this.selectedManual) {
      this.router.navigate(['toc', this.selectedModel, this.selectedManual.toc]);
      console.log("manual is " + event.value);


    }
  }

  private getManualFromManualList(toc: string): any {
    if (this.selectedModel && this.manuals) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.manuals.length; i++) {
        if (this.manuals[i].toc === toc) {
          return this.manuals[i];
        }        
      }
    }
    return null;
  }


  showFindPublicationDialog() {
    this.findPublicationClick.emit('show');
  }
}
```

.html...

```
<section class="side-nav-selects">
  <div class="model-selection">
    <h5 class="model-selection-title">Select your Model</h5>
    <h5 class="model-selection-title title-mini">Model</h5>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-select value="{{selectedModel}}" placeholder="Select a Model" (selectionChange)="changeModel($event)" [disabled]="!models || models.length == 0">
        <mat-select-trigger class="model-selection-trigger" *ngIf="selectedModel">
          {{selectedModel}}<mat-icon class="offline-ready-selected" *ngIf="offlineService.isElectron && selectedModel == '407'">done</mat-icon>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option class="model-selection-option" *ngFor="let model of models" [value]="model">
          {{model}}<mat-icon class="offline-ready" *ngIf="offlineService.isElectron && model == '407'">done</mat-icon>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="publication-selection">
    <h5 class="publication-selection-title">Select your Publication</h5>
    <h5 class="publication-selection-title title-mini">Publication</h5>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-select value="{{selectedManual ? selectedManual.toc: null}}" placeholder="All" [disabled]="selectedModel == null" (selectionChange)="changeManual($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let manual of manuals" [value]="manual.toc">{{manual.manual}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the incorrect behavior because trackRoute() was an async function awaiting this.loadManuels(), but loadManuels() was not a promise, it was an Observable.  This caused a few null values.  In making these changes (below), the issue was resolved.

```
 trackRoute() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.children.length > 0) {
      const routeModelName = this.routeService.getParameter('model');
      const routeManualName = this.routeService.getParameter('manual');
      this.selectedModel = routeModelName;
      this.loadManuals(routeManualName);
    }
  }


  loadManuals(manualName?: string) {
    this.manuals = undefined;
    this.selectedManual = undefined;
    if (this.selectedModel) {
      this.tocService.getModelToc(this.selectedModel)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.manuals = data.toc;
        if(manualName) {
          this.selectedManual = this.getManualFromManualList(manualName);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```